# Backbone marionette Listing the values from the server

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, backbone.js, marionette

I am new to Backbone.marionette.js and developing a sample application with spring MVC. i am able to make a call to server to add new data but `i am not able to display the sample data available in controller using backbone.marionette.js`.

following are the detailed files : `main.js`

```
$(function() {
    Puppet.start();
});

puppet.controller.js

PuppetController = {

    PUPPET_STARTED_EVENT : "puppet:started",
    ROUTER_STARTED_EVENT : "Router:started",
    MAIN_LAYOUT_RENDERED_EVENT : "Layout:Main:rendered",
    TEMPLATE_PRELOADING_COMPLETED_EVENT : "Template:preloaded",

    fireRouterStartedEvent : function() {
        Puppet.vent.trigger(this.ROUTER_STARTED_EVENT);
    },

    onRouterStartedEvent : function(listener) {
        Puppet.vent.on(this.ROUTER_STARTED_EVENT, listener);
    },

    firePuppetAppStartedEvent : function() {
        Puppet.vent.trigger(this.PUPPET_STARTED_EVENT);
    },

    fireTemplatePreloadingCompletedEvent : function() {
        Puppet.vent.trigger(this.TEMPLATE_PRELOADING_COMPLETED_EVENT);
    },

    onTemplatePreloadingCompletedEvent : function(listener) {
        Puppet.vent.on(this.TEMPLATE_PRELOADING_COMPLETED_EVENT, listener);
    },

    fireMainLayoutRenderedEvent : function() {
        Puppet.vent.trigger(this.MAIN_LAYOUT_RENDERED_EVENT);
    },

    onMainLayoutRenderedEvent : function(listener) {
        Puppet.vent.on(this.MAIN_LAYOUT_RENDERED_EVENT, listener);
    }
};
```

`puppet.create.`js

```
Puppet.module("CreatePuppet", function(CreatePuppet, Puppet, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

    var CreatePuppetModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url : 'api/create'
    });

    var CreatePuppetView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template : "#create-puppet",
        events :{
            "click #create-puppet-button" : "creatPuppet",
            "click #list-puppet-button" : "listPuppet"
        },

        creatPuppet : function(){
            var puppetModel = new CreatePuppetModel();
            puppetModel.set("firstName",$("#first-name").val());
            puppetModel.set("lastName",$("#last-name").val());
            puppetModel.save();

        },

        listPuppet : function(){
            alert("Table button is clicked");
        },

    });

    Puppet.addInitializer(function() {
        Puppet.preloadTemplate("#create-puppet");
        CreatePuppet.view = new CreatePuppetView();
        PuppetController.onMainLayoutRenderedEvent(function() {
            Puppet.MainLayout.layout.puppetForm.show(CreatePuppet.view);
        });
    });
});

puppet.js

Puppet = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

Puppet.templateIdsToLoad = [];
Puppet.preloadTemplate = function(templateId) {
    Puppet.templateIdsToLoad.push(templateId);
};

Puppet.getContextPath = function(contextPathSuffix) {
    return '/api' + contextPathSuffix;
};

Puppet.addRegions({
    mainContainer : '#main-container'
});

Puppet.on("initialize:after", function() {
    var loadAllTemplates = Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.preloadTemplates(Puppet.templateIdsToLoad, null);
    $.when(loadAllTemplates).done(function() {
        PuppetController.fireTemplatePreloadingCompletedEvent();
    });
});

PuppetController.onRouterStartedEvent(function() {
    Backbone.history.start();
    PuppetController.firePuppetAppStartedEvent();
});

puppet.layout.js

Puppet.module("MainLayout", function(MainLayout, Puppet, Backbone,
        Marionette, $, _) {

    var Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template : "#main-container-layout",
        regions:{
            puppetForm : "#puppet-form"
        }
    });

    Puppet.addInitializer(function() {
        Puppet.preloadTemplate("#main-container-layout"); 
        // why to load twice, why not to give the reference like template
        PuppetController.onTemplatePreloadingCompletedEvent(function() {
            MainLayout.layout = new Layout();
            Puppet.mainContainer.show(MainLayout.layout);
            /* what is this mainContainer -> 1. is predefined
                                             2. user defined if so where is it defined */
            PuppetController.fireMainLayoutRenderedEvent();
        });
    });
});

puppet.router.js

Puppet.module("PuppetRouter", function (PuppetRouter, Puppet, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

    var Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    });

    Puppet.addInitializer(function () {

        PuppetController.onMainLayoutRenderedEvent(function () {
            PuppetRouter.router = new Router({
                controller: PuppetController
            });
            PuppetController.fireRouterStartedEvent();
        });
    });
});
```

under templates folder

```
main-container-layout.htm

<div id="puppet-form"></div>

create-puppet.htm

<label>First Name : </label>
<input type="text" id="first-name"/>
<label>Last Name : </label>
<input type="text" id="last-name"/>
<input type="button" id="create-puppet-button" value="Save"/>
<input type="button" id="list-puppet-button" value="Table"/>
<div id="puppet-preview"></div>

puppet-preview.htm

<div class="hex-row">
    <div id="firstNameID"><%= firstName %></div>
    <div id="lastNameID"><%= lastName %></div>
</div>

index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Puppet Show</title>

    <link href="assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/puppet/css/puppet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-container"></div>

<!-- Backbone Marionette -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/backbone.marionette/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/backbone.marionette/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/backbone.marionette/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/backbone.marionette/backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/backbone.marionette/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/backbone.marionette/backbone.marionette.templates.js"></script>

<!-- backgrid Framework -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/backgrid/js/backgrid.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Puppet Framework -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/puppet/js/puppet.controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/puppet/js/puppet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/puppet/js/puppet.layout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/puppet/js/puppet.create.js"></script>


<!--Routing has to be the last module-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/puppet/js/puppet.router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/puppet/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

spring service class :

```
  package com.hexgen.puppet;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import com.hexgen.puppet.CreatePuppet;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    @Controller
    public class PuppetService {

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/create")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        void createOrder(@RequestBody CreatePuppet request) {
            System.out.println(request);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        List<Puppet> getGroups() {
            List<Puppet> puppets = new ArrayList<Puppet>();
            Puppet puppet = new Puppet();
            puppet.setFirstName("Mayank");
            puppet.setLastName("Kumar");
            puppets.add(puppet);

            puppet = new Puppet();
            puppet.setFirstName("Shylendra");
            puppet.setLastName("Bhat");
            puppets.add(puppet);

            puppet = new Puppet();
            puppet.setFirstName("Akash");
            puppet.setLastName("Waran");
            puppets.add(puppet);

            puppet = new Puppet();
            puppet.setFirstName("Shreyas");
            puppet.setLastName("Lokkur");
            puppets.add(puppet);

            puppet = new Puppet();
            puppet.setFirstName("Anthony");
            puppet.setLastName("Raj");
            puppets.add(puppet);

            puppet = new Puppet();
            puppet.setFirstName("Dheemanth");
            puppet.setLastName("Bharadwaj");
            puppets.add(puppet);

            puppet = new Puppet();
            puppet.setFirstName("Prasanna");
            puppet.setLastName("Adiga");
            puppets.add(puppet);

            return puppets;
        }
    }
```

I have `not added code for displaying the details available in server file, to be hones i don't know how to`,

Please help me to get this done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using models properly. Models represent data models on the server, so you shouldn't have a model to create puppets, only a single `Puppet`model. Backbone will determine the url to use for creation on its own.

In addition, there's a problem your model's `url`: you seem to only have a URL for creation.

By default, Backbone expects a restful API: it will send a POST request to the server when you save a new model. When you want to retrieve a model, it will try to generate the appropriate url.

In the code you have above, the `url`returned for any model is "api/create", but you probably want it to be something like "puppets/3" (where 3 would be the model's `id`attribute).

For you to be able to properly retrieve a model instance, you need to have a Puppet model (repalcing the one you have) with a `urlRoot` property (and no `url`). The `urlRoot` would be "puppets" for example. Then, when you fetch a model instance, Backbone will automatically send a GET request to "puppets/3" to get the proper model instance.

Another problem with your code above is that you aren't instanciating any view with a model instance. Just because you've created a puppet and have a template to show information doesn't mean it gets magically displayed.

You need to define a view, and provide it with a puppet model instance when you instanciate it. Curretnyl, you're just displaying an empty layout with a region (no views).

You might want to take a look a the free pdf here : http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf

It's the sample to [my book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction), and explains in more detail the basics of how models, collections, and views work. It will get you started with Marionette.